# How does momentjs handle addition or subtraction in terms of months or year

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

My question is how does momentjs handle addition or subtraction in terms months or years when there is a leap year or months that have different days in them such as March has 31 days and April has 30 days

An example is does it set it months to `30.4167 days` by default or does it do some calculations on how many days will be in a month in different years or the difference of how many days there will be between March or April

`moment().add(1, 'months');` is this equal to `30.4167 days` for every month or `730.001 hours` for every month?

How is momentjs handling this

Comment: In what sense?  if you increment a month, it makes no difference if it's a leap year if that's what you mean.

Comment: https://github.com/moment/moment

Comment: @Keith what I mean is does it set its default months to `30.4167 days ` when adding or subtracting or there is something else to it, I have updated the question

Comment: No, it uses proper date time handling.  If each month has different days, it will have different days.  eg.  adding 1 month to 31st March, will give 30th April because there are only 30 days, and subtracting 1 month, would give 28/29 Feb, depending on leap year.

Comment: @Keith Thank, but is there a way to handle this programmatically if I were not to use momentjs

Comment: Yes,.  But there is a little bit more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without moment.js, this solution seems to work well.

Basically set the month to the current month + the number of months.

One problem this causes is that adding 1 month to say 31st, and the next month only had 30, would give you the 1st of the next month.

To fix this, you can check for it.  If the new day of the month is different to the original, then we overflowed and we can just set the day to 1 and subtract 1 day to handle this.

Below is an example, if you run you will also see 28 & 29 of Feb with the leap year difference.

```js
const aday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

function addMonth(dt, m) {
  const r = new Date(dt);
  r.setMonth(r.getMonth() + m);
  if (dt.getDate() !== r.getDate()) {
    r.setDate(1);
    r.setTime(r.getTime() - aday);
  }
  return r;
}

const first = new Date("2019-12-31");

for (let l = -10; l < 10; l += 1) {
  const second = addMonth(first, l);
  console.log(`${second.toDateString()} - ${l} months`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = moment('2015-11-31');
var addMonth = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'M');
```

for years

```
var addYear = moment(currentDate)..add('years', 1).format('L');
```